# AWS EC2 Run python program for a month straight

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am writing a program in Python that will need to be having an uptime of 30 days straight. It is connecting to an MQTT-client, and listens for messages for a number of topics.

I have using an EC2 server instance running Linux AMI and I wonder how I could set this up to run constantly for this duration of time?

I was looking for cronjobs and rebooting every X days, but preferably the system should have no down time if possible.

However, I am unsure how to set this up and make sure the script restarts if the server/program was ever to fail.

The client will connect to an OpenVPN VPC through amazon, and then run the script and keep it running. Would this be possible to setup?

The version I am running is:
 
Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0.20180811 x86_64 HVM GP2

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI" 
VERSION="2018.03"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this by using Auto Scaling to automatically maintain the required number of EC2 instances. If an instance becomes unresponsive or fails health checks, auto scaling will launch a new one. See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-maintain-instance-levels.html

You'll want to make an AMI of your system to use to launch new instances, or maybe put your configuration into a [user data script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I will look into auto scaling! I tried enabling autostart for OpenVPN but found the system commands "systemd", "systemctl" and "update-rc" did not work. However, I did set up an "chkconfig openvpn on" - will this be enough to keep the openvpn starting at startup?

Comment: What distro of linux are you running? It'll be much easier to manage things if you've got systemd. Did you have appropriate privileges when you tried to enable autostart?

Comment: I added the server information to the original post. I did run it as root user, so all privileges were in place. Just receiving the "command not found" on systemd/systemctl

Comment: I could launch another instance of AWS server if that would make it easier, do you have a certain OS/type you would recommend for this project?

Comment: Trying using Amazon Linux 2, it has systemd by default https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/

Comment: why not use AWS IoT to listen to MQTT and put the messages through Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

If your use case is simply to receive messages over MQTT I would recommend that you take a look at the [AWS IoT Core](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/) service as a solution rather than running an EC2 instance. This will solve your downtime issues because it's a managed service with a high degree of resiliency built-in.

You can choose the route the messages to a variety of targets, including storing them in S3 for batch processing or using AWS Lambda to process them as they arrive without having to run EC2 instances. With Lambda, you get 1 million invokes per month for free so if your volume is less than this, your compute costs will be zero too.